# Combining keys and values of two different dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm new to python and am trying to merge two dicts

```
d1 = {
    'A': '1',
    'B': '2',
    'C': '3',
    'D': '4',
    'E': '5'
}

d2 = {
    'X': '!',
    'Y': '@'
}
```

I'm trying to merge the keys of both the dicts so that the result looks like this:

```
d3 =  {
    'A_X': '1!',
    'B_X': '2!',
    'C_X': '3!',
    'D_X': '4!',
    'E_X': '5!',
    'A_Y': '1@',
    'B_Y': '2@',
    'C_Y': '3@',
    'D_Y': '4@',
    'E_Y': '5@',
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just iterate over the dictionaries and combine them

```
d3 = {}
for k1,v1 in d1.iteritems():
    for k2,v2 in d2.iteritems():
        d3[k1+'_'+k2] = v1+v2
```

Another more cryptic but pythonic way to do it:

```
d3 = {k1+'_'+k2:v1+v2 for k1,v1 in d1.iteritems() for k2,v2 in d2.iteritems() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
from itertools import product

d1 = { 'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4', 'E': '5' }
d2 = { 'X': '!', 'Y': '@'}

d3 = {'_'.join([k1, k2]):''.join([d1[k1], d2[k2]]) for k1, k2 in product(d1.keys(), d2.keys())}

print(d3)
# {'E_X': '5!', 'C_X': '3!', 'D_Y': '4@', 'B_Y': '2@', 'A_X': '1!', 'D_X': '4!', 'A_Y': '1@', 'C_Y': '3@', 'B_X': '2!', 'E_Y': '5@'}
```